# PHP: multiple button with different name to update MySQL database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an problem, I have multiple button generate with `while`, with different names (`button[$nostation]`).

Now, I want to update MySQL database (table: `smt`, column: `no`) with the same id (`$nostation`).

How I can generate AJAX function for that?
[image]
**This is my code:**

```
<?php
$query1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM smt WHERE no <= 15");
while ( $data=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $nostation = $data['no'];
    $namastation = $data['name'];
    echo "
    <div class='col-xs-2-2'>
        <form action='coba.php' method='post'>
        <button name='button[$nostation]' value='2' style='background-color:#02780d; width:140px; height:75px; margin : 2px; border-radius:10%;'>
        <center>
        <b style='font-size:15px; color: #fff; font-family:Calibri;'>$namastation</b>
        </center>
        </button>
        </form>
    </div>
";}?>
```

And this is my code for **update database with PHP:**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$array=$_POST['button'];
foreach ($array as $nostation => $value) {
    $updch=mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE smt SET status='$value' WHERE no='$nostation'");
}?>
```

How I can update with AJAX without refreshing the page?

Comment: what do you really need? your code is open to SQL Injection

Comment: @aku tok what you actually want show us in picture??

Comment: @zimorok how i can update data in mysql with ajax without refreshing the page..

Comment: show us in picture??

Comment: if you have a lot of button, it will be a bit tricky. Unless, the current page showing the whole set of button is set to one unique ID. See @KUMAR answer for details

Comment: @aku tok what  happens??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View Part :-**

```
<?php
$query1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM smt WHERE no <= 15");
while ( $data=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $nostation = $data['no'];
    $namastation = $data['name'];
    
?>
    
    <div class='col-xs-2-2'>
        <form method='post'>
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nostation;?>" id="name_<?=$nostation;?>" name="name">
         <button type="submit" id="button_<?=$nostation;?>" data-id="<?=$nostation;?>">SAVE</button>
        <center>
        <b style='font-size:15px; color: #fff; font-family:Calibri;'>$namastation</b>
        </center>
        </button>
        </form>
    </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

**jQuery / AJAX Part:-**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){           //when DOM is Ready.
    $("[id^=button_]").click(function () {  //when Button is Clicked.
        var id = $(this).data('id');       // Get the ID of the button that was clicked on.
        var name = $("#name_"+id).val();   // value from `input` which is connected the clicked button.
       // console.log(id+"---"+name);
        $.ajax({                          // AJAX request
            url: 'update.php',            // send request to server.
            method: 'POST',               // method is POST.
            data: {                       //data which is sent to server.      
                id: id,name: name
            },
            success: function (data) {    //success function called.
            alert(data);                  // alert success data.
            } 
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**update.php:-**

And in the php-side We catch it by:-

```
echo $id = $_POST['id'];
echo $name = $_POST['name'];
//use update query.
```

**Note:-** For more info regarding **click()**

https://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: thanks,, thats work, i have try from the morning until now.. and thats work,, thanks so much.. im sorry for my bad english and my bad explanation. :)

Comment: @aku tok hey , if this answer is solved your problem then please mark green tick as an accepted answer and upvote  answer please for future readers.